# Display selected combobox item according to current item in parent datacontext

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

I have a wpf app that displays a Label in read-only mode and a ComboBox in edit mode.  When the user clicks the 'Edit' button, the label is hidden and the ComboBox becomes visible  (using a BooleanToVisibilityConverter).

The ItemsSource of the ComboBox is set to its lookup table (via *auditorsViewSource*), and the DataContext of the TextBox is set to the parent table (via *auditStatementsViewSource*).

Here is my xaml:

```
<!-- Auditor info -->
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{StaticResource auditStatementsViewSource}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Label Content="Auditor:" Name="lblAuditor" />

    <!-- readonly data -->
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource VisibleWhenReadOnly}">
      <TextBox Name="txtAuditor" >
        <TextBox.Text>
          <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="Auditor.GivenName"/>
            <Binding Path="Auditor.Surname"/>
          </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
      </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- editable data -->
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource CollapsedWhenReadOnly}" >
      <ComboBox x:Name="cboAuditor" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  DisplayMemberPath="Surname" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource auditorsViewSource}}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding Source=txtAuditor, Path=Auditor.Surname, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

The ComboBox displays the items from the base (*auditors*) table correctly, but displays the first record in the table (according to the ORDER BY clause).  How do I get it to initially show the item from the current (*auditStatements*) record, (ie, the Auditor that was being displayed by the readonly label), preferably in xaml?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `Binding` to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property works best if you are `Binding` an *actual* element from the collection that is data bound to the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property. As you are *not* using an actual element from the `ItemsSource` collection, you might have to do things somewhat differently.

On possible solution is for you to use the `SelectedValue`, `SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` properties instead. Please see the [How to: Use SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, and SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788714%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for full details on using this method to access the selected item.